# Change a version of a code of a fastapi deployed in an instance ec2 aws

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, fastapi

I have deployed an api (fastApi) in an instance EC2 AWS with cloning a repository github and nginx but i have changed the code of the api and i need to deployed my api with the modifications.

I have cloned again the repository but i still have the old code which is deployed.

Comment: Did you pushed the changed code to the repository?

Comment: Yes I have pushed the new version of code in github

Comment: Then plz check branch name

Comment: In repository in EC2?